# Cannot Download Azure Publish Settings

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azureportal, azure-sdk

Each time I [run the command `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/get-azurepublishsettingsfile?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) it navigates me to [`http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301775`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301775) which tells me [**No subscriptions found**](https://manage.windowsazure.com/Error/NoSubscriptions). I have been fighting this issue for months now - MS please help! I am unable to use the **Powershell SDk** because the wrong default directory is chosen every time I navigate to [`portal.azure.com`](http://portal.azure.com)

[image]

My Azure account has (2) directories associated with it and it **always** chooses the directory without any subscriptions. Anyone have a workaround? I cannot find a way to remove or disable a linked directory as it is permanently linked to my email.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you can't access old portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) as well or is that something you can do?

Comment: @GauravMantri correct - same results. for now I can use the **[Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)** (`az webapp list`, etc.), just can't use the legacy PS sdk

Comment: Reading through the documentation, can't you specify the name of your Azure AD as `-Realm` parameter?

Comment: Ensure that you have a subscription in your azure account. You can use `Get-AzureRmSubscription`  to check it .This script works in whichever  directory you login.

When you using powershell to login Azure ,have you specific your Tenant ID that has a subscription like this ?

    Login-AzureRmAccount -tenantId 48efaf10-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-94998e5f2332

Comment: @GauravMantri - great suggestion! tried using `-Realm`, but the result is still the same, we are using Bizspark - maybe this configuration isn't supported

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT - **Azure RM** interface appears to be working fine in PS - seems like the **Azure CLI** shares a similar login process/workflow. However, the legacy **Azure Powershell SDK** login process seems stuck - would be helpful to have a workaround for legacy scripts we we still use many of these cmdlets for production